# Next.js & Facebook OAuth - Type error in NextAuth JWT callback (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jwt, next-auth

I'm using Facebook for authentication and trying to get the access token so I can make API calls. This is in Next.js typescript, using NextAuth.

`pages/api/auth/[...nextAuth].ts`:

```ts
...
export const authOptions = {
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }) {
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token
        token.id = profile.id
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    }
  },
...
```

This is basically identical to [the docs](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks).

Since I'm using typescript, [the docs also say to use module augmentation](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/typescript#module-augmentation).

`next-auth.d.ts`

```ts
...
declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    id: string;
    accessToken: string;
  }
}

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    user: {
      id: string;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting this type error. Should I just set all params to `any`, or is there a better way?

[image: Image of type error]

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is because you haven't specified a type for the authOptions variable. Adding NextAuthOptions type should fix the error message.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
```

The parameters you add in next-auth.d.ts file are for extending the NextAuth types, so you could add custom parameters. Adding type any there would not do anything.